# How to hide NSCollectionView Scroll indicator

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I have an NSCollectionView and I would like to hide the horizontal scroll indicators.

I've tried

```
        collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.verticalScroller?.isHidden = true
```

But it is not working.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this line of code. collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.horizontalScroller?.isHidden = true

Comment: Have you figured this out? I have the same problem but unchecking the "Show xyz Scroller" does not remove the scroll indicator. I think the NSCollectionViewFlowLayout might add the indicator again.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @Jonathanff Hi, Have you figured this out?

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 7):

**hidden** didn't work for me too.

The only way I found to hack this, is by changing inset:

(**scrollViewCollectionView** is of type **NSScrollView**, this example is while creating **NSCollectionView** programmatically)

```
scrollViewCollectionView.documentView?.enclosingScrollView?.scrollerInsets = NSEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)
```

Please note: My NSCollectionView is horizontal, and less then 100 height, this is why this hack resolved in a hidden indicator.

Comment: This gets rid of the scroller button, but not the gutter for the scrollbar.

Answer (score 3):

Override `hasHorizontalScroller` or `horizontalScroller` to `false` and `nil` will cause `NSScroller` not to be displayed, and `NSScrollView` will not respond to scroll events.

This means that you can't scroll through `NSScrollView`'s many scrolling methods.

When `hasHorizontalScroller = true`, `horizontalScroller != nil` will cause a drawing error.

```
 class MyScrollView : NSScrollView {

    // !!! Don't use this !!!
    override var hasHorizontalScroller: Bool {
        get {
            // return false will cause NSScroller not to be displayed
            // and NSScrollView will not respond to scroll events,
            // this means that you can't scroll through NSScrollView's many scrolling methods.
            false
        }
        set {
            super.hasHorizontalScroller = newValue
        }
    }

    // !!! Don't use this !!!
    override var horizontalScroller: NSScroller? {
        get {
            // return nil will cause NSScroller not to be displayed,
            // but it still occupies the drawing area of the parent view.
            nil
        }
        set {
            super.horizontalScroller = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

[image: wrong usage preview1]

[image: wrong usage preview2]

This is the way to hide `NSScroller` and respond to scroll events correctly. Only useful in versions above 10.7:

```
class HiddenScroller: NSScroller {

    // @available(macOS 10.7, *)
    // let NSScroller tell NSScrollView that its own width is 0, so that it will not really occupy the drawing area.
    override class func scrollerWidth(for controlSize: ControlSize, scrollerStyle: Style) -> CGFloat {
        0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an outlet for the ScrollView which contains the CollectionView as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW9bP.png). I've named mine `@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewScrollView: NSScrollView!`
2. in `viewDidAppear()` function add:

   `collectionViewScrollView.scrollerStyle = .legacy`
   `collectionViewScrollView.verticalScroller?.isHidden = true` - for vertical scroll
   `collectionViewScrollView.horizontalScroller?.isHidden = true` - for horizontal scroll

For some reason, in my case it only works if I set the `collectionViewScrollView.scrollerStyle` to `.legacy`. Not sure why, but it works.

Comment: It worked for me, Its easy to close indicators for `NSCollectionView` but it extends from `NSScrollView` so it makes closed of its indicators.

Answer (score 1):

Setting "Show Vertical Scroller" or "Show Horizontal Scroller" in storyboard doesn't remove the scrollers without setting constrains (height and width) of Bordered Scroll View of Collection View. After I did that and unchecked "Show Vertical Scroller" and "Show Horizontal Scroller" in Attributes Panel in storyboard they disappeared.

Comment: Where exactly should I put the constraints?.
The scrollView of the collection view already have leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints.

Comment: do width and height on the scrollView

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem and just solve it. You can write your own custom `NSScrollView` and override 2 stored property: `hasHorizontalScroller`, `horizontalScroller`, and 1 function `scrollWheel(with:)`. Here's my code:

```
class MyScrollView: NSScrollView {
    override var hasHorizontalScroller: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
        set {
            super.hasHorizontalScroller = newValue
        }
    }

    override var horizontalScroller: NSScroller? {
        get {
            return nil
        }
        set {
            super.horizontalScroller = newValue
        }
    }
    //comment it or use super for scrroling
    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {}
}
```

And don't forget to set `Border Scroll View` class to `MyScrollView` in .xib or storyboard.
Enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

If someone still needs it, this one trick should work

```
collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.horizontalScroller?.alphaValue = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve that via storyboard

[image]

Comment: Xcode throws "'hidden' has been renamed to 'isHidden'"

Comment: On the storyboard those are already unchecked and scrolling indicator is still visible

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same problem. MCMatan is right. Please adjust the position of scroller to some place invisible.

```
scrollView.scrollerInsets = NSEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -10, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**for Swift 4 & 5 in UIKit:**

for Horizontal:

```
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

For Vertical:

```
collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Comment: This is UIKit. The question was about AppKit

Comment: Thanks this is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
In my case, the horizontal and vertical scroller of the collection scroll view are only hidden if do exactly as follow:

1. In Interface Builder.
1.a. Select Scroll View —> Attributes Inspector:
    + Uncheck Show Horizontal Scroller.
    + Uncheck Show Vertical Scroller.
    + Uncheck Automactically Hide Scroller.
1.b. Select Size Inspector:
    + Uncheck Automatically Adjust.
1.c. Select Clip View —> Size Inspector:
    + Uncheck Automatically Adjust.
2. In code do exactly as follow:

[self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[self.scrollView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
[self.scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:NO];
[self.scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
[self.scrollView setAutomaticallyAdjustsContentInsets:NO];
[self.scrollView setContentInsets:NSEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -NSHeight([self.scrollView horizontalScroller].frame), -NSWidth([self.scrollView verticalScroller].frame))];
[self.scrollView setScrollerInsets:NSEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -NSHeight([self.scrollView horizontalScroller].frame), -NSWidth([self.scrollView verticalScroller].frame))];
[self.scrollView setScrollEnable:NO];

NSClipView *clipView = (NSClipView *)[self.scrollView documentView];

if ([clipView isKindOfClass:[NSClipView class]])
{
    [clipView setAutomaticallyAdjustsContentInsets:NO];
    [clipView setContentInsets:NSEdgeInsetsZero];
}

Then the NSCollectionView will fit to the Clip View as same width and height without the horizontal and vertical scrollers.
```